# Dataflow Error Monitoring and Alerting

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

What is the best way to set up Dataflow resource monitoring and alerting on Dataflow errors?

Is it custom log based metrics only?

Checked Cloud Monitoring - Dataflow is not listed there - no metrics available.
Checked Error Reporting - it is empty too, despite a few of my flows failing.

What do I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update March 2017**: Stackdriver Monitoring Integration with Dataflow is now in Beta. Review [user docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/stackdriver-monitoring), and listen to Dataflow engineers [talking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEteVlEHa60) about it at GCP Next.

For the time being you could set up alerts based on Dataflow logs (go to Stackdriver Logging and set up alerts there). We are also working on better alerting using Stackdriver Monitoring and will post an announcement to our [Big Data blog](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/) when it's in beta.